# How to check this checkbox within a table without any ID

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am writing a Selenium code with Python to automate certain tasks on my website. However, I am unable to check this checkbox. Are there any recommendations? 
This is the line of code for the checkbox I am trying to check:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="" name="delete0">
```

I have tried 2 different ways and both does not work.

```
1. driver.find_element_by_class_name("delete0").click()
2. driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'").click()
```

I am expected to check the checkbox, however nothing happened and instead, I have an error message of:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@type='checkbox' because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@type='checkbox'' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: The error says your `[` needs its `]`. And `name` is not class name (`find_element_by_class_name` looks in `class`, not in `name`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided,

- The first code trial failed:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_class_name("delete0").click()
  ```

  - Reason: The attribute `class_name` is not **`delete0`** but a *blank space*
- The second code trial failed:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'").click()
  ```

  - Reason: Locator had *Syntax Error* as you have missed the `]`

---

### Solution

You can use either of the following solution:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='checkbox'][name='delete0']").click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='delete0']").click()
  ```